# Visual Studio Project Template for JavaScript/VBScript?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, vbscript

Has anyone had luck finding a Visual Studio Project Template for JavaScript and/or VBScript?  I would like to use VS as my script IDE but get frustrating with the lack of integration.

I'm hoping someone else was just as frustrated as me and already came up with a solution.

Answer (score 14):

1. File->new->New Website (Shift-Alt-N).
2. Select 'Empty Web site' (ignore other controls)
3. right-click solution explorer, select 'add new item'
4. select HTMLPage (name it index.html).
5. right-click solution explore, select 'add new item;
6. select jscript file.

If that's not what you're looking for, could you clarify?

Comment: I am referring to the lack of VBScript template project and/or file.

Comment: This might not have solved his question, but it definitely solved mine. Thanks. Now I just need to find out how to specify which HTML page to open up on.

Answer (score 3):

VisualStudio 2008 sp1 has much improved javascript support. It isn't perfect, but it does a pretty good job of formatting, syntax highlighting and intellisense. There are a few things that would be nice to have like automatic doc creation, but for the most part it works about as good as any other js "ide".

Some articles...

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/06/21/vs-2008-javascript-intellisense.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/vs2008JSIntellisense.aspx
http://blogs.ipona.com/james/archive/2009/01/14/jquery-1.3-and-visual-studio-2008-intellisense.aspx

Answer (score 1):

In addition to jayrdub's response, VBScript intellisense and formatting was last officially supported in Visual Studio 2005. But it was then later added back in for Visual Studio 2008 SP1 at the demand of the user community.

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=290845
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=292379

So as long as you're not on VS 2008 RTM, you shouldn't have much of an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
http://krestenm.blogspot.com/2007/12/vbscript-projects-in-visual-studio2.html